# Show list form DispForm.aspx "in window" instead of as a dialog box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, list-form

Does anyone know how to get a list form to display as an aspx page by default instead of as a popup iframe? For example, when a user clicks on a list item, DispForm.aspx opens as part of the same page as the list.

EDIT: I'm working in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the List Settings page for that list and choose "Advanced settings," you can set "Launch forms in a dialog?" to "No." Selecting "No" will cause these actions to navigate to the full page.

Comment: I'm working in Visual Studio, so would this be somewhere in the Schema.xml file for the list?

Comment: You need to set NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE" in the schema. Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125309/disabling-modal-dialogs-for-list-forms-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Found that questions about a minute before you posted it, but thanks!

Comment: @Danny- some times when I choose this setting it has no effect. Why in some lists does the item open in a new window and others still retain the pop-up?

Comment: Same problem here - the setting doesn't have any effect.